# Should any threads reside outside of the thread pool?

Tags: java, multithreading

When using a thread pool, is it beneficial to still use singular thread objects for a specific task. I'm wondering in terms of a server in Java, whether or not the thread which is listening for connections, should share its resources with any other threads which are then allocated from this one listening thread? I may also be missing the point as I'm not familiar with this concept.

Comment: Yes, I don't see a reason to why you would want to place the accept thread in a thread pool.

Comment: Okay that's great - all I wanted to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, singular tasks that have to run concurrently can have their own threads outside of the thread pool. Forcing every thread to be part of the pool might obscure your design because you need all kinds of machinery to make concurrent tasks look like worker threads.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create two pools, one for listening and one for internal tasks.  This way you're never putting your server at risk of not being able to listen for connections.

The pool for internal tasks can be small if it's only a thread now and then, but at least it's safely isolated.

Comment: This answer is useful to me as I was also unsure whether it is good practise to use multiple thread pools, so thanks.

Comment: I would have the listening task loop until finished and never give up the thread.  That way another thread cannot put the listening task at risk.

Answer (score 0):

Resource sharing might be necessary in cases where your server needs to maintain a global application state (e.g. using an AtomicLong for the number of requests served by your server etc.). Your main thread would typically wait, ready to accept incoming connections/requests. You then update the global state (like hit counter), create a new "job" based on the new request (typically a Runnable or Callable) and submit it to a thread pool (java.util.concurrent) provides them.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of a thread pool is just to help you manage your threads.  In other words, a thread pool handles the creation and termination of threads for you as well as giving work to idle threads.  Threads that are blocked or waiting will not receive new tasks.

Your connection listener will probably be in an infinite loop waiting for connections and thus never be idle (although it could be in a wait state).  Since this is the case, the connection listener thread will never be able to receive new tasks so it wouldn't make sense to pool it with the other threads.

Connection listening and connection handling are also two different things.  From that perspective the connection listener shouldn't be pooled with the connection handlers either.

Answer (score 0):

SImilar to @larsman's comment, I would do what ever you feel is simpler and clearer.  I have tended to use one thread pool for everything because it appeared to be easier to manage.  You don't have to do it that way and the listening task can be its own thread.